# Property does not exist on type '{}' in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have get data using http call. But, i have show above error in compile time.

**user.component.ts**

```
this._user.saveUsers(model).then(data => {
    if(data.success==true){
        this.router.navigate(['/user/list']);
    }else{
        console.log("data")
    }
});
```

**Note:** my object is dynamic. depends on my http call

**Error:**

app/users/users.component.ts(33,21): error TS2339: Property 'success' does not exist on type '{}'.                      app/users/users.component.ts(34,38): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'.                         app/users/users.component.ts(76,25): error TS2339: Property 'success' does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: `this._user.saveUsers(model).then(data => { console.log(data)})` check n tell what do you get in console???

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about lines 33 and 34 because they are not shown in your code but with 76 you have to put

```
data: any
```

Or

```
data: {success: any}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you perhaps post the method `saveUsers`'s definition.
If you are using `es6-promise` then take a look at the [typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts#L11). As you can see the promise class accepts a generic interface `T` which can be used to define the type of object that can be passed to `then`. So in case the function `saveUsers` is returning a promise i.e. something like

```
function saveUsers(model: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {...})
}
```

You need to make the function accept a generic and pass it to the returned promise like

```
function saveUsers<T>(model: any) {
    return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {...})
}
```

So now what you can simply do is call `saveUsers` as

```
saveUsers<{success: boolean}>(model).then(data => {...})
```

or just pass whatever is the interface of the data being passed to then.

Even if it is not an es6 promise just check the typings of whatever it is you are returning. There will definitely be a way of defining the type of data being passed to then.

## UPDATE

To add to `micronyks`'s answer, if you are using something along the lines of `axios` to execute a network call inside `saveUsers` the returned response will have [this](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#response-schema) format so in your case it would be `data.data.success` inside the then block

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong it should be,

```
this._user.saveUsers(model).then(data => {
    if(data.data.success==true){                //<<<===changed
        this.router.navigate(['/user/list']);
    }else{
        console.log("data")
    }
});
```