# Property does not exists on type '{}' using Promises

Tags: typescript, lambda, promise, anonymous-function

I am accessing a property of an object returned from a resolved promise.

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // Get result
    resolve(result)
}).then(r => console.log(r.id))
```

Typescript compiles the code and the code works but my IDE is complaining about `r.id`

> [ts] Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'.

What is the 'TypeScript' method of dealing with this? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709205/property-does-not-exist-on-type-in-angular2) seems to have the same issue but I cannot understand the given solutions. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49467180/817379) talks about using interfaces but im not sure how I would apply that to the `then()` function of a `Promise`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Typescript will not be able to tell the result type of the `Promise` by the usage of `resolve`, you need to specify the result type explicitly as a generic parameter to `Promise`:

```
new Promise<{ id: string }>((resolve) => {
    // Get result
    resolve(result)
}).then(r => console.log(r.id))
```

You can replace `{ id: string }` with any type, as bonus typescript will check that `resolve` is called with the correct result type.

**Edit**
I am assuming that instead of `// Get result` there is some more complicated code that requires use of the `Promise` constructor. If you already know the result, you can just use `Promse.resolve(result)` which will type the promise correctly as @BenjaminGruenbaum pointed out in the comments

Comment: Or just call `Promse.resolve(result)` which TypeScript will gladly take care of.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum true, true, I am assuming there is more code where the `//Get result` comment is, but I will add the simplified version :)