# Return promise values to calling function in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

I have created a promise to fetch values from a service and then return it `trans` and `confidence` to `transcript` and `conf` respectively inside `save_data` function. How will i use return those values to the calling function and rest of the code should not get executed till all the promise is returned successfully.

```
 fetchTransValues() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var trans =  this.service.getTranscriptValue();
          var confidence =this.service.getConfidenceValue();
        }, 1000);
      });
    }
    async save_recording(){  

      this.fetchTransValues().then(function(message) {
        this.answer_loading=true;
        let formData=new FormData();
        const transcript_arr = [];
        const confidence_arr = [];

        
        ....
        ....
        this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'api/auth/get-results', formData).subscribe(response  => {
      
      
        });
      });
```

[image]

Value inside promise:
[image]
Any solution to resolve this issue, Thanks

Comment: Move the "rest of code" inside the `then` callback, or put it in a function and call that function from within that `then` callback. Or make `save_data` an `async` function, and use `await` on `this.fetchTransValues()` (without `then`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: That `console.log(message)` logs _"Hello asynchronous world!"_ is not already enough of a hint?

Comment: @trincot Thanks all for the solution, will i be able to use `trans` and `confidence` variable inside then block

Comment: No, for that you need to pass them to `resolve()` as argument, like so: `resolve({trans, confidence})`. Then `message` will have those as properties.

Comment: @trincot As you have told i have moved my code to then block but getting `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getTranscriptValue')` but this method is available and i have updated my complete code in question can you please check

Comment: That is because you use `this`, and the value of `this` is not the same when you use a callback `function`. Use an arrow function instead. Also, don't use `async` if you don't use `await`.

Comment: @trincot I'm using like this  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function() {    var trans =  this.service.getTranscriptValue();
          var confidence =this.service.getConfidenceValue();   }, 1000);   });   but getting same error can you please provide some link for the same

Comment: I'm talking about the callback that is given to `then`. Just change all callbacks to arrow functions, and you won't have an error that relates to `this`.

Comment: @trincot In console error is in these lines of codes `var trans this.service.getTranscriptValue();       var confidence =this.service.getConfidenceValue();` inside `fetchTransValues` method

Comment: Can you edit your question and focus on the problem you are having now, with the most recent code? I am lost. Please remove **any** code that is not relevant to the problem. Make it minimal. Just enough to make the problem reproducible.

Comment: @trincot Yes i have updated my code, initially `save_recording` is called then i want rest of the code to execute in `save_recording` after `fetchTransValues` returns updated value, getting this error : `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getTranscriptValue')` can you ploease check,

Comment: Where do you use `message`? Do you need it at all? What is the purpose if `transcript_arr`, and of `confidence_arr`. They are never used. Are they relevant to your problem? Is the call to `this.http.post` relevant to your problem?

Comment: @trincot No i want to use only `trans` and `confidence` in the calling method don't need message, yes i will be using `confidence_arr` and `transcript_arr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve your promise with the `trans` and `confidence` results, and capture those when the promise resolves. As you have used `async`, use `await`. This also solves the `this` problem that your code has:

```js
class Container {
    service = {
        getTranscriptValue() { return "dummy" },
        getConfidenceValue() { return "another dummy" }
    }
    
    fetchTransValues() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                const trans = this.service.getTranscriptValue();
                const confidence = this.service.getConfidenceValue();
                resolve({trans, confidence});
            }, 1000);
        });
    }

    async save_recording(){  
        const {trans, confidence} = await this.fetchTransValues();
        console.log("received", trans, "and", confidence);
        this.answer_loading = true;
        // ..etc
    }
};

new Container().save_recording();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, getting this error `Property 'trans' does not exist on type 'Promise<unknown>'.` service method actually returns array values that's why i was using `const` previously

Comment: Corrected now.. `const` is fine also.

Comment: Getting this error `Property 'trans' does not exist on type '{}'`

Comment: I turned my answer into a runnable snippet. It is important to change all callbacks (that use `this`) to arrow functions.

Comment: when i comment these lines `resolve({service_transcript, service_confidence});`  then it is working but i can't use these values in calling function

Comment: Did you run the snippet in my answer?

Comment: When i use your code that is working on editor then also i'm getting the error that i have uploaded in the screenshot

Comment: I cannot reproduce that issue. Please provide the code that makes it possible to reproduce the issue for us.

Comment: Code is almost same will i have to define type also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49854385/property-does-not-exists-on-type-using-promises as asked in this question? Value is also returned from the service as shown in screenshot

Comment: Definitely. I was dealing with this on the JavaScript level, as your original question was about asynchrony, but has gone through several revisions and is now a completely different question than it was from the start. And yes, this is related to typescript typing.

Comment: It got solved when i gave type  `return new Promise<{ trans: any,confidence:any }>((resolve, reject) => {`  Thanks for the solution, Should i use then block also because my main motive was next block should only execute after previous blocks of code returned proper results, or without then also it will work the same way

Comment: The `await` will make sure that the code below it is only executed later, when the promise has resolved, so no `then` is needed.